# Using Objective-C bitmask in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mailcore2

I'm porting some objective-c code to Swift. I need to check a bitmask but I'm getting an error:

`MCOMessageFlag is not convertible to Bool`

How should I be accessing this from Swift.

```
self.message.flags = NSNumber(int: self.message.flags.intValue & ~MCOMessageFlag.Flagged)
```

I'm using the MailCore2 library.

Edit:

Here is the line of objective-c I'm porting:

```
[self.message setFlags:[NSNumber numberWithInt: self.message.flags.intValue & ~MCOMessageFlagFlagged]];
```

Edit:

> RawOptionSetType no longer implements BooleanType by default, so standard bitmask checks (if opt & .Option {...) only work if you add BooleanType protocol conformance manually.

I'm guessing this is my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.rawValue` to get the value you need:

```
MCOMessageFlag.Flagged.rawValue
```

Comment: That was my first thought but it didn't help. The error just changed to: ```Int is not convertible to Bool```. I've added the line of objective-c I'm porting if that helps.

Comment: Flags is an NSNumber.

Comment: CMD-Click on `MCOMessageFlag` to see the definition. That might give a clue.